# Select multiple elements in a row using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

My code is as follows

```
var users = MyTable.AsEnumerable()
                      .Select(x => new { x.Field<string>("Col1"),x.Field<string>  
                       ("Col2")}).ToList();
```

On compiling I get

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must
> be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to give a name to each of the fields in the anonymous type

```
var users = MyTable.AsEnumerable()
  .Select(x => 
     new { Col1 = x.Field<string>("Col1"), Col2 = x.Field<string>("Col2")})
  .ToList();
```

The only time the name of an anonymous type field can be omitted is when the expression itself is a simple name that the compiler can use.  For example if the expression is a field or property then the name can be omitted.  In this case the expression is a generic method call and has no name the compiler will use

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var users = MyTable.AsEnumerable()
                      .Select(x => new
                      {
                        Col1 = x.Field<string>("Col1"),
                        Col2 = x.Field<string>("Col2")})
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: can you explain why please?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
var users = MyTable.AsEnumerable()
                      .Select(x => new
                      {
                        Col1 = x.Field<string>("Col1"),
                        Col2 = x.Field<string>("Col2")})
                        .ToList();
```